# Unable to make curl requests from subdomains on the same server machine to each other

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have a server with the following configurations -                       centOs7, php7, apache 2.4 - hosting a website with some sub domains. I realised that I cannot make a cURL requests between the sub domains. Such calls will always return false. I need to resolve this because the subdomains need to communicate with each other for several reasons.

I will appreciate any support that can help resolve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Include a Host header, and point to 127.0.0.1 if on the same host, if you are having DNS resolution issues.